# How close to 1 does $x$ have to be to ensure that the given function is within a distance of $0.5$ of its limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I hemmed and hawed over whether I should ask about this. The question seems clear enough, but it just seems far too easy. I'm worried I'm misunderstanding it.

I am confused about part b of this question in my textbook.

> **Part a**
>
> Use numerical and graphical evidence to guess the
>   value of the limit $$\underset{x \to 1} \lim \frac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$
>
> **part b**
>
> How close to $1$ does $x$ have to be to ensure that the
>   fun­ction in part a is within a distance $0.5$ of its limit?

So basically, as I understand it, $x$ would have to be in the range $(0.5, 1.5)$ to be within a distance of $0.5$ of $1$.

I must be misunderstanding this, right?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214054/use-numerical-and-graphical-evidence-to-guess-the-value-of-the-limit-underset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the limit is $6$.

The question is asking us to determine $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-1|<\delta$ would ensure that

$$\left|\frac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{x}-1} -6\right| < \frac12$$

This picture might help you.

[image]

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, I need to find the range of values for x such that $\left|\frac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{x}-1} -6\right| < \frac12$?

Comment: yup, I don't think you are required to find exact value though, perhaps just a range of values close to $1$ that would satisfy taht value.

Comment: Thank you! This makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214054/use-numerical-and-graphical-evidence-to-guess-the-value-of-the-limit-underset/3214074#3214074), I did show that, at least locally,
$$\frac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}\sim 6+\frac{15}{2}(x-1)$$ So, you look for the range of
$$\frac{15}{2} |x-1| \leq \frac 12\implies |x-1| \leq \frac 1{15}$$ Then, ???